# I got a error when i need to insert 2 table

Tags: php, html, sql

```
    $Rnameth = $_POST['Rnameth'];
    $Rnameeng = $_POST['Rnameeng'];
    $faculty=$_POST['faculty'];
    $major = $_POST['major'];
    $Rdename_thf=$_POST['Rdename_thf'];
    $Rdename_ths=$_POST['Rdename_ths'];
    $Rdename_engf=$_POST['Rdename_engf'];
    $Rdename_engs=$_POST['Rdename_engs'];
    $Rsubject=$_POST['Rsubject'];
    $Rcredit=$_POST['Rcredit'];
    $Rstatus=$_POST['Rstatus'];
    $approv1=$_POST['approv1'];
    $Ryear=$_POST['Ryear'];

    $Pname=$_POST['Pname'];
    $Pidcard=$_POST['Pidcard'];
    $Pposition=$_POST['Pposition'];
    $Pnamereg=$_POST['Pnamereg'];


 $sql = "INSERT INTO curriculum_reg(`Rnameth`, `Rnameeng`, `faculty`, `major`, `Rdename_thf`, `Rdename_ths`, `Rdename_engf`, `Rdename_engs`, `Rsubject`, `Rcredit`, `Rstatus`, `approv1`, `Ryear`) 
        VALUES('$Rnameth','$Rnameeng','$faculty','$major','$Rdename_thf','$Rdename_ths','$Rdename_engf','$Rdename_engs','$Rsubject','$Rcredit','$Rstatus','$approv1','$Ryear', '$Rfile'); 
        INSERT INTO professor (`Pname`, `Pidcard`, `Pposition`, `Pnamereg`) VALUES ('$Pname', '$Pidcard', '$Pposition', '$Pnamereg'LAST_INSERT_ID());";
        $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql)or die(mysqli_error($con) . "<br>".$sql);
        mysqli_multi_query($con,$sql);
```

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` what was this ?

Comment: Please mention what error you get?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO professor (`Pname`, `Pidcard`, `Pposition`, `Pnamereg`) VALUES ('', ' at line 3
INSERT INTO curriculum_reg(`Rnameth`, `Rnameeng`, `faculty`, `major`, `Rdename_thf`, `Rdename_ths`, `Rdename_engf`, `Rdename_engs`, `Rsubject`, `Rcredit`, `Rstatus`, `approv1`, `Ryear`, `Rfile`) VALUES('','','คณะแพทยศาสตร์','','','','','','','','1','2','', ''); INSERT INTO professor (`Pname`, `Pidcard`, `Pposition`, `Pnamereg`) VALUES ('', '', '', '')

Comment: As i checked in database curriculum_reg, you haven't mention the proper values.

Comment: Please check the "faculty" field datatype and change the collation into UTF

Comment: yes i'm done ,datatype = varchar and utf but i need to insert 2 table  id from curriculum_reg to Pnamereg of Table professor. how i do?

Comment: You've got two queries. Which means that `mysqli_query()` cannot handle it, while `multi_query()` can. Remove the first. Also you should really look into using a prepared statement instead...

Comment: There's also a syntax error near `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, missing a comma

Comment: still error T_T

Comment: You'll need to be more specific which exact error you're getting. We can't see your screen.

Answer (score -1):

Your **curriculum_reg** table column count is the 13 and you are insert value is 14 please check the query and tri to insert agen.

and remove **$Rfile** variable

Comment: Thank you , it not error now but don't insert to table T_T

Comment: when i'm check error, this still  SQL syntax error again T_T